# Error de aplicación en Heroku con nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, mongoose, heroku

Estoy tratando de desplegar mi aplicación en Heroku y me da un 'Application error', ya lo había desplegado sin problemas antes y funcionaba bien, comencé a agregar algunas cosas más, cree un api, agrege POST's y GET's, volví a darle push y dejó de funcionar. Me da este error al abrir mi aplicación en heroku, cabe mencionar que de modo local funciona bien, incluso utilizando ngrok desde Vs.

> Application error
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
> heroku logs --tail

Al ver los logs desde heroku me dice esto:

```
2021-02-18T14:28:25.869957+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=chatbotlaboratorio.herokuapp.com 
request_id=a189272f-353d-4015-b7c7-ccfffd4d5e43 fwd="187.228.67.38" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-18T14:28:26.080311+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=chatbotlaboratorio.herokuapp.com 
request_id=4fdfaba7-9df2-4629-86c2-63df53a6185e fwd="187.228.67.38" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-18T14:36:01.159267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=chatbotlaboratorio.herokuapp.com 
request_id=5794baee-2ada-4b3b-a1c8-2704c1a5ca88 fwd="94.130.167.103" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-02-18T14:36:01.366649+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=chatbotlaboratorio.herokuapp.com 
request_id=87bc0bb7-ce64-4df1-9e9a-f4901698eaa8 fwd="94.130.167.103" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-02-18T14:41:14.391693+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=chatbotlaboratorio.herokuapp.com 
request_id=65463729-4be1-4d79-9d6c-3ebfbd1da7f0 fwd="187.228.67.38" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-18T14:41:14.659036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=chatbotlaboratorio.herokuapp.com 
request_id=68a27808-7b8c-4436-9a60-2becf4e18448 fwd="187.228.67.38" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-18T14:41:58.578306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to 
starting
2021-02-18T14:42:03.075789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 
`npm start`
2021-02-18T14:42:06.460302+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-18T14:42:06.460321+00:00 app[web.1]: > jimenezbots@1.0.0 start /app
2021-02-18T14:42:06.460321+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-02-18T14:42:06.460322+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488076+00:00 app[web.1]: 
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488099+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488100+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488100+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488102+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 
'../chatbotDialogflowNodejs/config'
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488102+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488103+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488105+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488105+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488105+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488106+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require 
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488106+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> 
(/app/server.js:5:16)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488107+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488107+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488107+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488108+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488109+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488109+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488109+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488110+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ 
'/app/server.js' ]
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488110+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-02-18T14:42:07.518235+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-02-18T14:42:07.518886+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-02-18T14:42:07.530496+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! jimenezbots@1.0.0 
start: `node server.js`
2021-02-18T14:42:07.530760+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-02-18T14:42:07.531075+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-02-18T14:42:07.531340+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
jimenezbots@1.0.0 start script.
2021-02-18T14:42:07.531573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a 
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-02-18T14:42:07.542523+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-18T14:42:07.542855+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this 
run can be found in:
2021-02-18T14:42:07.543029+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-18T14_42_07_532Z-debug.log
2021-02-18T14:42:07.608653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-18T14:42:07.676122+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2021-02-18T14:42:07.684683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to 
starting
2021-02-18T14:42:11.825694+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 
`npm start`
2021-02-18T14:42:14.925472+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-18T14:42:14.925644+00:00 app[web.1]: > jimenezbots@1.0.0 start /app
2021-02-18T14:42:14.925645+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-02-18T14:42:14.925650+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679796+00:00 app[web.1]: 
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679842+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679842+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679843+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679843+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 
'../chatbotDialogflowNodejs/config'
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679844+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679844+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679845+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679845+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679846+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679846+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require 
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679847+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> 
(/app/server.js:5:16)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679847+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679847+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679848+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679848+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679849+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679850+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679850+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679850+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ 
'/app/server.js' ]
2021-02-18T14:42:15.679851+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-02-18T14:42:15.697511+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-02-18T14:42:15.698033+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-02-18T14:42:15.706610+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! jimenezbots@1.0.0 
start: `node server.js`
2021-02-18T14:42:15.706919+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-02-18T14:42:15.707107+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-02-18T14:42:15.707250+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
jimenezbots@1.0.0 start script.
2021-02-18T14:42:15.707371+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a 
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-02-18T14:42:15.716447+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-18T14:42:15.716824+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this 
run can be found in:
2021-02-18T14:42:15.717002+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
/app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-18T14_42_15_708Z-debug.log
2021-02-18T14:42:15.790661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-18T14:42:15.939560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
```

La versión de nodejs de Herou 14.15.5 y la local 14.15.4

El códgio de mi archivo server.js en mi webhook es el siguiente:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require("../chatbotDialogflowNodejs/config");


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// for parsing json
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: "20mb",
  })
);
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
    limit: "20mb",
  })
);

mongoose.connect(

  config.MONGODB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log("Hubo un error en la BD ", err);
    console.log("BD online");
  }
);

app.use("/messenger", require("./Facebook/facebookBot"));

//Siempre las rutas dentro del archivo api empezaran con /api/
app.use("/api", require("./routes/api"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.send("Chatbot Funcionando ");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Escuchando peticiones en el puerto ${port}`);
});
```

Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias!.

Comment: Puedes añadir los logs completos? parece que no los capturaste todos, no cambies la vista de los logs y reinicia todos tus dynos.

Comment: Listo, al reiniciar todos los dynos me arrojo esos errores en el log

Comment: Ahi indica que no se puede encontrar el modulo /app/server.js revisa si existe o si no estas utilizando rutas absolutas

Comment: Creo que identifico más o menos que pasa, creo que en el commit que desplegue el heroku eliminé el archivo config.js pero no se como subir el commit que ya lo tiene .

Comment: Me aparece algo asi en la consola al hacer push nuevamente:    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/chatbotlaboratorio.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Ya trate de hacer el merge y ni así se deja de decirme ese error

Comment: Haz lo siguiente, git pull --rebase

Comment: A veces cuando esto me pasa lo que hago es que clono el repo de nuevo y copio la carpeta .git en el repo original, luego hago add . y commit

Comment: Ya se desplegó correctamente, lo que hice para evitar el error fue quitar la linea que tenía para el acceso a mongodb en config y ponerla directamente en el archivo server e hice commit y push. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si a alguien en el futuro le sirve, lo que a mì me funcionò fue quitar la parte en el còdigo de arriba el archivo server.js que dice "config.MONGODB" en la conexiòn de mongoose ya que tomaba ese string desde el archivo config.js de manera equivocada, sòlo hacìa falta escribir "MONGODB"(como se llama la variable en config), hice git add , commit y push nuevamente y listo. Nota: de esta manera no funciona en local, asì que lo que yo hice fue crear otra branch, una para probar de manera local y otra para desplegar en heroku.

Answer (score -1):

En los logs se ve que el error es este:
2021-02-18T14:42:07.488102+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module
'../chatbotDialogflowNodejs/config'

posiblemente haya algun error al enlazar el archivo

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)